# Magento 2 - why are translations from my CSV file not loading

Tags: magento2, localisation, language, translation-dictionaries

I am using Magento 2.2.7 and theme Techno from Themevast.
My app/code/design structure looks like this:

```
frontend/tv_themevast_package/default
frontend/tv_themevast_package/techno1
```

Template is using both folders.

I have created `i18n` in both folders for my translations

```
frontend/tv_themevast_package/default/i18n/hr_hr.csv
frontend/tv_themevast_package/techno1/i18n/hr_hr.csv
```

and translations from `techno1` seem to be loading but translations from `default` are not.

I have tried putting translations from `default` into file that is in `techno1` but that didn't help.

When I was translating I have imported CSV file into excel, where I have created translations, and after that had to copy it to Google Sheets in order to get CSV file with double quotes as was in original.
Later I noticed that there are elements in translations like:

```
"Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href=""%1"">Sign in</a> or <a href=""%2"">create an account</a>","Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href=""%1"">Sign in</a> or <a href=""%2"">create an account</a>"
```

So as suggested I have tried replacing double-double quotes with `&quot;` but that didn't help.

```
"Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href=&quot;%1&quot;>Sign in</a> or <a href=&quot;%2&quot;>create an account</a>","Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href=&quot;%1&quot;>Sign in</a> or <a href=&quot;%2&quot;>create an account</a>"
```

**So question is:**

How can I use translations for `default` template?

Answer (score 1):

First change name hr_hr.csv to hr_Hr.csv

if this doesn't help, check that you don't have any space between ","

and last one:

Try to use:

/yourvendor/yourTheme/Magento_Reviews/i18n/hr_Hr.csv

```
"Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href=""%1"">Sign in</a> or <a href=""%2"">create an account</a>","Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href=""%1"">Sign in</a> or <a href=""%2"">create an account</a>"
```

or you need add ,module,Magento_Review at the end of translation:

```
"Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href=""%1"">Sign in</a> or <a href=""%2"">create an account</a>","Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href=""%1"">Sign in</a> or <a href=""%2"">create an account</a>",module,Magento_Review
```

Croatian language pack from mageplaza:
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-croatian-language-pack.html